# Scala: "number" interpolation

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

Scala has string interpolation like `raw"\n"` for raw strings.

Does it have anything like number interpolation e.g. `1px` for one pixel? A nice syntax for numeric units would both make code more readable and make it easier to write safer code.

Like strings, numbers have a nice literal syntax and are fundamental.

prefix notation `px(1)` is not how people write units:

```
case class px(n: Int)
```

And I don't think a postfix notation via implicit conversion can work:

```
case class Pixels(n: Int) {
 def px() = Pixels(n)
 def +(p: Pixels) = p match {case Pixels(m) => Pixels(n+m)}
}
implicit def Int2Pixels(n: Int) = Pixels(n)
```

1. it needs a dot or space or parens (i.e. not `(1 px)` or `(1)px` or `1.px`, which is not how humans write units).
2. it won't check types i.e. we want to explicitly cast between these numeric type-alias things and numbers themselves (i.e. `1.px + 2` and `1 + 2.px` and `def inc(p: Pixels) = p + Pixels(1)` with `inc(0)` all don't fail, because of the implicit cast, when they should).

Comment: I may be wrong, but I doubt it can be achieved. The reason is that `1f` and `1d` are considered numbers as well and it seems like Scala cannot figure out where the number part ends and the method part starts. Your approach would work fine with `String`s: `"1"px` would work great

Comment: The parser could desugar `1px` much as it does `s""`, with a `px` extension method on a special type instead of Int.

Comment: @som-snytt can you explain?

Answer (score 3):

You can define own string interpolation (more details [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html)):

```
implicit class UnitHelper(val sc : StringContext) extends AnyVal {
  def u(args: Any*): Pixels = {
    val pxR = """(\d.*)\s*px""".r   
    sc.parts.mkString match {
      case pxR(px) => Pixels(px.toInt)
      case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
    }
  }
}
```

Usage example:

```
val x = u"10px" + u"20px" // x = Pixels(30)
```

Pros:

- easy to add interpolation for any units: em, px, pt, cm, in

Cons:

- it is not type safe because string interpolation is runtime feature.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but as i said, it needs to be type-safe. otherwise, why use scala, right?

Comment: you might be able to make it type-safe, and have a better syntax, by using a different StringContext for each unit (i.e. not u"10px" but px"10"). as long as you don't clash with the builtins.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following implicit,

```
implicit def int2Pixels(n: Int) = new {
  def px = Pixels(n)
}
```

Then

```
1 px
res: Pixels = Pixels(1)
```

Here we invoke the `px` method on object `1`, a method that is not defined in `Int` and so the implicit takes a role.

Altogether,

```
case class Pixels(n: Int) {
  def px() = Pixels(n)
  def +(p: Pixels) = p match {case Pixels(m) => Pixels(n+m)}
  def +(m: Int) = Pixels(n+m)
}

// for enabling implicit conversion
import scala.language.implicitConversions 
implicit def int2Pixels(n: Int) = new {
  def px = Pixels(n)
}
```

and so

```
(12 px) + 1
res: Pixels = Pixels(13)

(12 px) + 1 px
res3: Pixels = Pixels(13)
```

For explanation on import see for instance [Why implicitConversions is required for implicit defs but not classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18915114/3189923) .

Comment: thanks for answering, but i had already proposed this problematic solution in my question, which states that i want 1. type safety and 2. better syntax.