# Understanding implicit conversions

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I'm reading Scala [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-conversions) of implicit conversions and decided to try it out:

```
object Main extends App {
    val test = TestConversion(100)
    test.its
}

class Test[T](val t : T) {
  def its = println(t)
}

object Test {
  def apply[T](t: T): Test[T] = new Test(t)
}

class TestConversion(v : Int) {
  val value = v
}

object TestConversion{
  implicit def implicitConversionTest2Int(ict : TestConversion): Test[Int] = Test(ict.value)
  def apply(v : Int) = new TestConversion(v)
}
```

As it's said:

> To define your own implicit conversions, you must first import
>   `scala.language.implicitConversions` (or invoke the compiler with
>   `-language:implicitConversions`). The feature must be explicitly enabled because it has pitfalls if used indiscriminately.

I tried it both in IntelliJ and online IdeOne and I didn't add anything special to make it compile.

What pitfalls it brings and why does it work without any imports?

Comment: This is some old stuff that you are reading. You don't have to import anything to use implicit conversions. You might have to add compiler flag, though or else it will give you compile-time *warnings*.

Comment: @sebszyller But what pitfalls do they talk about?

Comment: When you have many implicits it gets difficult to track them and reason about the code. This is one of the reasons why wildcard imports are so dangerous if not done cautiously.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915114/why-implicitconversions-is-required-for-implicit-defs-but-not-classes.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to import anything.
The idea is that you can declare implicit conversion function wherever you want in the scope.
For example:

```
case class Coins(amount:Int)
case class Bills(amount:Int)

object Main {
  implicit def billsToCoins(bills:Bills):Coins = Coins(bills.amount * 100)

  def printCoins(coins:Coins) = println(s"You have ${coins.amount} coins." )

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit ={
    printCoins(Bills(3))
  }

}
```

I have declared here implicit function `billsToCoins` so it is available in scope of the `main` function. The only thing needed for the function to act as implicit converter is to have the `implicit` modifier, compiler will find it and use. You see that the `printCoins` function takes argument of the `Coins` type but I was able to pass the value of `Bills` type and it was successfully created.
Here is the console output:

```
You have 300 coins.

Process finished with exit code 0
```